# JSON Paring - How to show second Level ListView

Tags: java, android, json

I am parsing JSON data into ListView, and successfully parsed first level of JSON in MainActivity.java, where i am showing list of Main Locations, like:

1. Inner Locations
2. Outer Locations

Now i want whenever i do tap on Inner Locations then in SecondActivity it should show Delhi and NCR in a List, same goes for Outer Locations as well, in this case whenever user do tap need to show USA

JSON look like:

```
{
    "all": [
        {
            "title": "Inner Locations",
            "maps": [
                {
                    "title": "Delhi",
                    "markers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Connaught Place",
                            "latitude": 28.632777800000000000,
                            "longitude": 77.219722199999980000 
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Lajpat Nagar",
                            "latitude": 28.565617900000000000,
                            "longitude": 77.243389100000060000
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "NCR",
                    "markers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Gurgaon",
                            "latitude": 28.440658300000000000,
                            "longitude": 76.987347699999990000
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Noida",
                            "latitude": 28.570000000000000000,
                            "longitude": 77.319999999999940000
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Outer Locations",
            "maps": [
                {
                    "title": "United States",
                    "markers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Virgin Islands",
                            "latitude": 18.335765000000000000,
                            "longitude": -64.896335000000020000
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Vegas",
                            "latitude": 36.114646000000000000,
                            "longitude": -115.172816000000010000
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:** But whenever i do tap on any of the ListItem in first activity, not getting any list in SecondActivity, why ?

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://10.0.2.2/locations.json");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("all");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrieve JSON Objects
                    map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));

                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                    Intent sendtosecond = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    // Pass all data rank
                    sendtosecond.putExtra("title", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.TITLE));
                    Log.d("Tapped Item::", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.TITLE));
                    startActivity(sendtosecond);
                }
            });         
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    strReceived = in.getStringExtra("title");
    Log.d("Received Data::", strReceived);
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://10.0.2.2/locations.json");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("maps");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrieve JSON Objects
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));

                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `strReceived`

Comment: @Raghunandan i am getting correct value, like if i do tap on Inner Locations then getting: 06-12 09:50:01.620: D/Received Data::(4657): Inner Locations

Comment: @Raghunandan  jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray(strReceived);

Comment: now what is `strReceived`?

Comment: for easy way, you create a class,and arraylist of that object and parse this json in the first activity and then send only those things to second activity that you need to show there

Comment: title: tapped item name @Raghunandan

Comment: I think `strReceived` is `String` variable. The value passed from first activity is fetched in second and stored in `strReceived`. So please tell us what is the value of `strReceived`. If you press on first item in listview then what value are you getting in `strReceived`?

Comment: @Aniruddha yes you are right, 06-12 09:50:01.620: D/Received Data::(4657): Inner Locations

Comment: Can you print the `receivedString` right before you try to parse it to an object? just to make shure you're not parsing an empty string.

Comment: So strReceived = Inner Locations?? In your json there is no tag with `Inner Locations`, maybe that's why it is giving error. I guess instead of Inner Locations it should be `maps`.

Comment: yep as @Aniruddha said, there is no jsonarray named Inner Location . that's why you are getting error.

Comment: you need so send maps object to your next activity.inner location is just a text

Comment: @WaqarAhmed how can i do this ?

Comment: you need to do something like this map.put(jsonobject.getString("title"), jsonobject.getString("map"));

Comment: so key will contain innerlocation and value will the map object that you can convert into json object and parse that

Comment: @Raghunandan will you help me ?

Comment: @Sophie what is `strReceived` is it `all`??

Comment: @Raghunandan yes like: Inner Locations, Outer Locations

Comment: @Raghunandan Now i want whenever i do tap on Inner Locations then in SecondActivity it should show Delhi and NCR in a List, same goes for Outer Locations as well, in this case whenever user do tap need to show USA

Comment: @Sophie before coming to parsing Why do you need to make get the json from url twice. Once you get you can cache the same and parse

Comment: @Raghunandan boss i never ever worked with this kind of JSON, so please guide me and show me the code what should i need to use ? as you can see in my JSON i have to show three level lists, for an example: if user do tap on Inner Locations then need to show Delhi and NCR in a second activity's list and when user do click on Delhi then need to show Connaught Place and Lajpat Nagar

Comment: @Sophie are you passing `Inner Locations` to Second activity? I mean `strReceived = "Inneer Locations"`?

Comment: @Aniruddha yes as you can see in my JSON i have to show three level lists, for an example: if user do tap on Inner Locations then need to show Delhi and NCR in a second activity's list and when user do click on Delhi then need to show Connaught Place and Lajpat Nagar

Comment: Ok, I understood it. But with the JSON format you are currently using it is kind of difficult to do. See, you're passing `Inner Locations` from 1st to 2nd activity. Then in 2nd you're trying to get the value with the `key Inner Locations`. Have a look at your JSON, does it contain a `key` with Inner Locations? NO..! That is why it is giving error with no value found.

Comment: @Aniruddha forget the past, forget everything happened yesterday, just check my updated code specially SecondActivity.java

Comment: Oops didn't see it. What is happening now? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i am not getting error neither getting any data into List

Comment: @Raghunandan i hope you are working on my solution !

Comment: @Sophie you need to know that you are getting JSONObject. You have assumed `maps` comes under the root JSONObject node which is not the case. There are many json parsing tutorials pls have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below method:-

```
        try
        {
            JSONObject j = new JSONObject("your json response");
            JSONArray all = j.getJSONArray("all");
            for (int i = 0; i < all.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject data = all.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("title       =>"+data.getString("title"));
                JSONArray maps = data.getJSONArray("maps");
                for (int k = 0; k < maps.length(); k++)
                {
                    JSONObject data_sec = maps.getJSONObject(k);
                    System.out.println("name        => "+data_sec.getString("name"));
                    System.out.println("latitude    => "+data_sec.getString("latitude"));
                    System.out.println("longitude   => "+data_sec.getString("longitude"));

                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
        .getJSONfromURL("http://10.0.2.2/locations.json");

        try {
        // Locate the array name in JSON
        jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("all");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        // Retrieve JSON Objects
        map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
        map.put("index", i);

        arraylist.add(map);
        }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
        Intent sendtosecond = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        // Pass all data rank
        sendtosecond.putExtra("title", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.TITLE));
        sendtosecond.putExtra("index", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.INDEX));
        Log.d("Tapped Item::", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.TITLE));
        Log.d("Tapped Item Index::", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.INDEX));
        startActivity(sendtosecond);
        }
        });
        }
        }
        }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        strReceived = in.getStringExtra("title");
        strReceivedIndex = in.getStringExtra("index");
        Log.d("Received Data::", strReceived);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://10.0.2.2/locations.json");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("all").getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(strReceivedIndex)).getgetJSONArray("maps");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrieve JSON Objects
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));

                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: but i am not using any index in my JSON

Comment: i know that but you can not get jsonArray from title you have to get it only using index of that jsonObject.

Comment: what is try to you do is first get title from all jsonArray and using this title get map jsonArray in another screen is it or else?

Comment: so in my what is i do is first get title and index from all jsonArray and try to pass this title and index to another activity and in another activity try to get map jsonArray from appropriate jsonObject of all jsonArray.